# How to pass the value of a textbox in a datagrid to javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a textbox inside my datagrid whose id need to be passed to javascript.The id of my datagrid is Datagrid1 and that of textbox is txtItem.All these are inside a contentplaceholder.Now i have passed the id of textbox as ct100_ContentPlaceholder1_Datagrid1_txtItem.It shows an error in my javascript as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".How can i pass the id of this textbox which is inside a datagrid to javascript.

Comment: Show us your code, the part that generates this error. Additionally, view the source of the rendered page and determine the exact ID of the textbox(es).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a textbox inside your grid probably you have multiple instances of it, with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can access all textboxes inside your grid like that :

```
function getTextBoxesInsideGrid()
{
    var gridClientID = '<%= grid.ClientID %>';
    jQuery.each($("#" + gridClientID + " input[type='text']"), function ()
    {
      var textValue = this.val();
      // do something
    });
}
```